# Building Boost on Linux - library names

Tags: linux, boost, building

I am trying to build an application which depends on [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries).  So I downloaded Boost 1_41_0 to my Linux box and followed the instructions found on the Boost site for Unix variants,
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html.

They basically suggest that I run ./bjam install, which I did.  The build completed successfully.  However, the library names don't seem to match the Boost naming convention described both in the documentation above, and what is specified in the makefile of the application I am trying to build.

I noticed that there are a bunch of options that I can specify to bjam and I tried to play with those, but no matter what happens I can't seem to get it quite right.  My understanding is that the libraries should go into the $BOOST_ROOT/lib directory.  This is where the libraries show up, but named:

```
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.so
libboost_thread.so.1.41.0
```

I'd expect them to be named libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-d-1_41_0 or something similar.

I did try ./bjam --build-type=complete --layout=tagged and I see:

```
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread-mt.a
libboost_thread-mt-d.a
libboost_thread-mt-d.so
libboost_thread-mt-d.so.1.41.0
libboost_thread-mt-s.a
libboost_thread-mt-sd.a
libboost_thread-mt.so
libboost_thread-mt.so.1.41.0
libboost_thread.so
libboost_thread.so.1.41.0
```

So, I am not sure if I should just make stage my -L directory?  Is there any documentation which describe this in more detail?

Answer (score 7):

The names was changed in 1.40.0 - see in [release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/news/version_1_40_0):

> Build System
>
> The default naming of libraries in
>   Unix-like environment now matches
>   system conventions, and does not
>   include various decorations.

They probably forgot to update this part in the build documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two variables here. First is "install" vs. "stage" (default). "install" copies both libraries and headers into a directory -- /usr/local by default, and you can then remove source tree. "stage" puts libraries to "stage/lib", and you should add "-L /stage/lib -I " flags.

Second is --layout=versioned and --layout=system. It seems like you have discovered what they do already, and indeed, system is default since 1.40. The getting started guide fails to mention this, and I've added an action item to update it. Ideally, you should talk to the authors of the application to use the system naming of boost libraries. If that's not possible, then building with --layout=versioned is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

From the Boost documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming, the convention is:

**-mt** Threading tag: indicates that the library was built with multithreading support enabled. Libraries built without multithreading support can be identified by the absence of -mt.

**-d** ABI tag: encodes details that affect the library's interoperability with other compiled code. For each such feature, a single letter is added to the tag:

```
Key     Use this library when:
s   linking statically to the C++ standard library and compiler runtime support libraries.
g   using debug versions of the standard and runtime support libraries.
y   using a special debug build of Python.
d   building a debug version of your code.
p   using the STLPort standard library rather than the default one supplied with your compiler.
n   using STLPort's deprecated “native iostreams” feature.
```

For example, if you build a debug version of your code for use with debug versions of the static runtime library and the STLPort standard library in “native iostreams” mode, the tag would be: -sgdpn. If none of the above apply, the ABI tag is ommitted.

Comment: How does one build a Boost with multithreading support? Boost's [Installation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html) does not mention it.

Comment: When building boost, use:
./b2 --build-type=complete --layout=versioned
This will generate each version of each library, including the multithreaded ones.

Comment: Thanks Riot. From [other discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293962/boost-libraries-in-multithreading-aware-mode) on Stack Overflow, it appears that Boost is multi-threaded by default. So if I perform `./b2`, then I get multi-threaded without decorations. Is that not the case?

Comment: I believe so - but if you want full control over what is and isn't included, i recommend using --build-type=complete and --layout=versioned and then simply selecting those built libraries that you actually wish to include.  No ambiguity in that situation, especially if the default behaviour changes in future.