# How do I make Boost multithreading?

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile the latest Boost c++ libraries for Centos. I 've used bjam install and it has placed the libraries in /usr/lib and /usr/lib64.

The problem is I need the -mt variants for a specific application to run. I cannot understand in the documentation how to create the multithreading variants. :(

Please give me a hint!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of 2293962 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293962/boost-libraries-in-multithreading-aware-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-mt is just distribution specific extension.
either edit your config file or create symbolic link to libboost_thread

```
andrey@localhost:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/libboost_thread*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 174308 2010-01-25 10:36 /usr/lib/libboost_thread.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     41 2009-11-04 10:10 /usr/lib/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 -> libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  49912 2008-11-01 02:55 /usr/lib/libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 2010-01-27 18:32 /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a -> libboost_thread.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 2010-01-27 18:32 /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.40.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 2010-01-27 18:32 /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.40.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89392 2010-01-25 10:36 /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.40.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build all variations of the boost binary libraries using the `--build-type=complete` option. For example:

```
bjam --build-type=complete stage
```

This will put all library files into `<your boost dir>/stage/lib/`