# clang: error: unknown argument: '-wall'

Tags: c, makefile

I was walking through [this](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex3.html) tutorial, where I had to create this `make` file:

```
 CFLAGS=-wall  -g

 clean:
   rm  -f  ex1
```

I then used the above `make` file in [this](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex3.html) tutorial, and ran the following command:

```
$ make ex3
```

When I did that, I got the following output:

```
cc -wall  -g    ex3.c   -o ex3
clang: error: unknown argument: '-wall'
make: *** [ex3] Error 1
```

Why did I get the error? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The option you're looking for is `-Wall`.

In general, options starting with `-W` indicate specific warnings or sets of warnings to enable or disable.